# remove Default in migration?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In the migration I alter `enabled` field to set to 1 value as default.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('client', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean('enabled')->default(1)->change();
    });
}
```

In `down()` method - How do I remove `default()` ? I know can do `default(0)` but default was never created during create table.

Comment: If nothing comes up, try considering writing a Raw Query in your `down()` method.

Comment: Try `$table->boolean('enabled')->change();` !

Answer (score 90):

Surprisingly or not, for `NOT NULL` fields `->default(null)` removes the default from a table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('client', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean('enabled')->default(null)->change();
    });
}
```

Just omitting the `default()` part doesn't work, since `laravel` makes a [diff](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.2.45/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/Grammar.php#L295) between [current state](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.2.45/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/Grammar.php#L315) and [current state + specified changes](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.2.45/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/Grammar.php#L330). No changes specified, no diff.

After that, [`doctrine`](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/v2.5.5/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php#L583) generates [ALTER TABLE statement](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/v2.5.5/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/AbstractPlatform.php#L2199), treating [`NULL`](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/v2.5.5/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php#L462) as [no default value](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/v2.5.5/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/AbstractPlatform.php#L2253-L2255).

With nullable fields though, from what I can see, `doctrine` doesn't let you simply drop the default. The only option is supposedly to make them `NOT NULL`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('client', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean('enabled')->nullable(false)->default(null)->change();
    });
}
```

Maybe with PostgreSQL you can get away [without converting to `NOT NULL`](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/3.0.0/src/Platforms/PostgreSQL94Platform.php#L533-L561), but that's to be confirmed.

Comment: A side note: Laravel migrations don't support changes to some column types. I just tried to change a `tinyInteger` column and it didn't work. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#modifying-columns for details.

Comment: It would be more intuitive if `->default(null)` would set `NULL` as default value and `->noDefault()` would remove default value (I thought about `->default(false)` but it should set `false` as default in Postgres...).

Comment: @Wirone just to clarify, if you want the default value of the column to be an actual null value, you just simply make the column nullable and it will always default to null. No need for additional DB methods within Laravel; just add ->nullable() to your column definition.

Comment: I would advise against this method because it looks like a trick and not documented. Just use plain SQL from another answer, it is simple and its meaning is perfectly clear. KISS principle.

Answer (score 12):

Since there is no way to remove this statement with Laravel functions, your down function must execute the statement as raw. It should be something like:

```php
public function down()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE client ALTER COLUMN enabled DROP DEFAULT');
}
```

In order to execute this migration, you need to include at the top of your migration:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Comment: Since the classname is already "DB" itself, it should suffice without the "DB" alias.